# Getting rid of certain spots on an image

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I have an image in which my region of interest are the dots in the middle. I would like to get rid of the pixels at the top right circled in blue. How can I solve it.

[image]

Comment: @MarkSetchell I can't crop an image that is being processed.

Comment: Depending on what you mean with "getting rid" you could set the pixels in "certain spots" to zero value.
You could crop the image by setting a cv::Rect around the ROI, subimage the image and copy it to a new image (or just work on the subimage) if all "certain spots" lie outside of the Rect.
You could create a mask (image with same size and CV_8UC1 type) with all "certain spots" valued zero if you apply a method allowing a mask.
If you don't know yet where "certain spots" are, you must find a way to distinguish between those spots and your "foreground". In that image maybea simple threshold.

Comment: @Micka How do I create a rect around ROI which in my case are the dots in the middle.

Comment: Depends on how you can identify "your case". If it is always similar quality to your given image I would try to first identify the dots with circle detection or blob detection methods. Then Try to find the "lines" with a RANSAC linedetection: choose randomly 2 of the dots and create a line through them, then test how many dots are close to that line (inlier). Repeat this until enough inlier are found, accept that line and remove the inlier dots. repeat until all 4 lines are dected. Compute the line-interscections. Extract min/max x/y coordinates. cv::Rect(miX,miY,miX+maX,miY+maY).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the image is binary. In that case:

If the "dots" (small circles) that you want to detect are larger than the spots you want to remove, you can apply a median filter on the image. The size of the median filter can be determined according to the size of the noise spots. Another possibility is to use morphological operations (erosion and dilation). All these operations are supported by OpenCV.

If the image is not binary, you can start by converting it to binary using a threshold value.